# CakePHP - Setup database with a form

Tags: php, database, cakephp, installation, edit

I would like to setup the database in CakePHP providing host, login and password with a form (so without writing the database.php file myself). The purpose is some kind of automatic setup of CakePHP (I would use this to provide salt and cypherSeed too).
Is this possible? What's the best way to do go? I read something about writing file via PHP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create/load your database connection from your controller you can have this data variable. I don't think it's a good idea to write database.php file with a form. 
So I would do something like this:

```
//Controller
$this->Formdatabase = ClassRegistry::init('Formdatabase');
$db_host = '';//load from file or DB
$db_user = '';//load from file or DB
$db_pass = '';//load from file or DB
$db_database = '';//load from file or DB
ConnectionManager::create("form_database", array(
      'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'persistent' => false,
      'host' => $db_host,
      'login' => $db_user,
      'password' => $db_pass,
      'database' => $db_database,
      'prefix' => '',
      'encoding' => 'UTF8',
      'port' => '',
));
$this->Formdatabase->useTable  = ''; //table you want to use. (in Model or controller)
//Model
<?php
  class Formdatabase extends Model {
public $useDbConfig = 'form_database';
  }
?>
//Now you can use $this->Formdatabase->find('...'); ...
```

Hope I could help, good luck!

Comment: Yes I thinc this could help. Thank you :-)